# Python: get first date of the week from calender week and year (working for 2020 but not for 2021)

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to extract the first date of the week from the year and the calender week (in Europe where the first calender week is the week that includes the 4th of January)

My code works correctly for

```
import datetime 
year=20
week=53
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-"+ str(week-1) +'-1-CET', "%y-%U-%w-%Z"))
```

the output is 2020-12-28 00:00:00 which is correct

for

```
import datetime 
year=21
week=1
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-"+ str(week-1) +'-1-CET', "%y-%U-%w-%Z"))
```

I get also 2020-12-28 00:00:00.The correct output would be 2021-01-04.

Could you please tell me where my mistake is?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `%V` instead of `%U` should make things easier.

Comment: Thanks, using %V in combination with %G for the year worked.